# Silverlight: Change style for state

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

My App.xaml looks like this:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         x:Class="mySilverlightApp.App"
         >
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"  Value="Calibri.ttf#Calibri"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to apply custom styling with `<Setter>` tags to ComboBoxes in my app. But I want to apply styling for different states of the ComboBox (MouseOver, etc).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, you'll have to create a control template in your implicit style.  Something like the following:

```
<Style x:Name="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                  ....
              </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can refer to this link for the default styles/controltemplates for the combobox:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

A great way to get started re-templating controls is using Blend.  You can right click a control you have dragged onto the artboard and use the "Edit Template -> Edit a Copy" command.  This will create a default controltemplate for you (the same one shown in the link I provided).

From there you can edit the mouse-over state in Blend by using the States tab.

There's alot going on here, but this should get you started on the right path.